# Is it possible to post comments on Instagram via API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

There is a POST method for to create comments, but it says the following:

> Create a comment on a media. Please email apidevelopers[at]instagram.com for access.

See: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#

So do I have to get whitelisted for to be able to post comments or is the access_token enough?

Comment: Why don't you email `Please email apidevelopers[at]instagram.com for access` and ask them?

Comment: You need to have special access granted to your Client ID. Go to the link in the error message and request access. Good luck though... they have not answered my requests for many months.

Comment: I can immagine that this can eventually take ages yes. Thanks for the info @celwell!

Comment: as krisrak has mentioned, you will need to email instagram to add your app to the commenting whitelist. This however seems to be taking a very long time to do and can take several weeks/months. My application (and many others) have been waiting to get confirmation back from Instagram for months now. It may take a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible to post comments on Instagram via API. You have to get whitelisted now, so you have to email. This was not the case before, you were able to use commenting in api whithout whitelisting, but because of some apps spamming and abusing the comments feature, commenting now has to be whitelisted

See more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/comments#create