# Post a comment on image in instagram

Tags: ios, instagram

I have been following this tutorial "http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/instagram-api-integration-in-ios-application/2/" and able to login and even fetch user's data like his images, likes and comments. But when it comes to posting like "comments on images" and "posting an image" it's really confusing.

I have searched online and come up this http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/ but I'm unable to incorporate this in my code, and from where to get media_id it's confusing and I'm not even sure whether this is exactly what I want.

Please anyone guide me how to proceed after this or if someone has some useful tutorial. Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+relationships",KCLIENTID,kREDIRECTURI]];
[instaLogin loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: The media id is so that instagram know which image to associate the comment with ?

Comment: So all of your images must have an ID associated with them? WHne you post yp a comment you need to include that ID in the url so that it can be assigned to the correct image... Does that help ?

Comment: Thank you I'm clear with media id but what would be the new url and how it would be settled or incorporated with current code from first link? please do tell me about that as well

Comment: Well the URL would be: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments (with the media id in the place of the token. Then you also add the ACCESS_TOKEN/TEXT in as the Paramters ?

Comment: api.instagram.com/v1/media{media-id}/comments?access_token=TOKEN_VALUE
this is what u meant?

Comment: Yeah if they are passed with the url.

Comment: I tried your code but when I convert string into url it shows nil

i.e as I was having a previous link that brought user data it works fine 

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c"

using NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=%@",                                                                                                                                        accessToken]]];

Comment: but now in this scenario url shows nil 

here it is NSString *testString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media{761688240037794812_261410739}/comments?access_token=%@/%@",accessToken, @"helloTesting"];
    
           NSURL *testUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:testString];

where as url is nil

Comment: Because that isn't a valid url. take the {} out.

Comment: still page not found. 

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c/helloTesting

Comment: You need a forward slash after media... ?

Comment: ohh sorry I forgot to show that. And now I get following error message

{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}

Comment: although my token is correct!

Comment: Well it obviously isn't.

Comment: Have you requested access to that end point ?

Comment: Yes I have, I just have edited the question and pasted the code that I used, is there anything wrong in that

Comment: If it's a valid url it's a valid url. I don't know why it won't work with instagram as I've never tried to use their API.

Comment: ohh thanks anyways I will see through further

Comment: There is something wrong with the URL because if there is any problem with token then my other call shouldn't have worked!
this works fine
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=%@",                                                                                                                                        accessToken]]];

Comment: after 
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=%@/%@",                                                                                                                                        accessToken, @"helloTesting"]]];

Comment: So is it working now ?

Comment: Yes its working on following url 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c

response is {"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
which is success. Now I have to see how to send comment along

Comment: ok. Just as an FYI you probably shouldn't post your access token on a public forum lol

Comment: haha ya I know but had to do it thought it could help me to get solution very soon :D

Comment: still can't find a better way to send comment along. Actually I'm unable to find anything on internet that shows how url will look a like, i.e either its query string or comment will go with parameter 
this is my url. 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c
now if I send message along following way 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c/msg
it gives 400 code error :/

Comment: You sure that access token is valid for that call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spotted you aren't constructing the URL Properly:

Try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/761688240037794812_261410739/comments?access_token=319219722.a1a262a.7ca4123804ee4506a63256519b32147c&text=test"];
```

******EDIT******

Make sure you are using GET,POST & DELETE properly. see the top of the link you provided. I suspect you are calling this with GET.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Comment: well it works as i've just tested it. You need to sperate the access token from the comments with the & then declare the text key. As it says on their site.

Comment: after hitting this url it fetches the entire data of an image like all comments and etc but the last parameter that you have passed as text=test has not been posted as comment there on that pic yet :/

Comment: OK well thats really a different question now.

Comment: Question was how to post a comment on picture, url seems fine now but still comment is unable to be there '

Comment: Which HTTP method are you using ?

Comment: one more thing to mention as you said we need to separate comments with access token via & sign I tried it and got an error of page not found and revert it to ? mark and it works fine

Comment: no not the comments word. but the text of the comments and the access token. as in my url. So you've changed it to POST and it adds the comment ?

Comment: Well I have figured out something, url is working fine it gives success which is 200 code but still can't post comment on that picture, this is because we need to send an email to Instagram with all the information of app they only they will let us post comment. have a look at this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069916/is-it-possible-to-post-comments-on-instagram-via-api

Comment: How to post comment in android if anyone knows then please help ?